# How to assign Vue.js 2 component value to main instance variable?

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm actually on the learning stage of Vue.js 2. I'm trying to append the component checkbox values to main Vue.js instance data array variable. However I always getting empty array in the  `{{ brandArray }}`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="app">
   <p>Brands</p>
  <app-brand></app-brand>

{{ brandArray }}

</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Vue.component('app-brand', {
        data: function() {
            return {
                 brands: [{
                    b_id: 1,
                    b_name: 'BRAND 1'
                }, {
                    b_id: 2,
                    b_name: 'BRAND 2'
                }, {
                    b_id: 3,
                    b_name: 'BRAND 3'
                }, {
                    b_id: 4,
                    b_name: 'BRAND 4'
                }]
            }
        },
        template: '<div><div class="checkbox" v-for="brand in brands"><label><input type="checkbox" @click="setBrand($event)" :value="brand.b_id"  v-model="this.brandArray" >: {{ brand.b_name }}</label></div></div>',
        methods : {
            setBrand: function (e) {

                if (e.target.checked) {
               console.log(e.target.value)
                }

            }
        }
    })


    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            brandArray: [],
            colour: [],

        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set `brandArray` in the root vue instance, but you tried to use it in the child component named `app-brand`, move `brandArray` to child component's data can help you overcome it.

Since vuejs2 doesn't allow two-way data flow. To share data between parent and child in vuejs, generally there're 3 ways often been used.

1. [Props-Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) (`.sync` modifier is just a syntax sugar of this method)
2. [Event Bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)
3. [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)

Comment: That's working fine and also I can print it inside the child component. However what if wanted to print it outside the child component, is it possible? perhaps is there any bind function available to do it?

Comment: I think you are looking for this document: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Comment: @FRSTAR I updated my answer to give you more detailed info. Please have a look.